# Record accelerometer sensor readings to SQLite or flat file?

Tags: android, sqlite, accelerometer, sensors

I'm writing an Android app to record and save high-rate accelerometer data (and later gyroscope data). The schema of my data will look like:

```
timestamp, x_accel, y_accel, z_accel
```

Should I save the data into SQLite or into a flat file (using FileWriter and BufferedWriter, as explained [here](http://androidgps.blogspot.com/2008/09/writing-to-sd-card-in-android.html))? Which one has the lowest latency or is more appropriate?

Eventually I need to import the data as a csv file into Excel to create graphs. So if I write to SQLite, I need to later write it out to csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either will work obviously, but my personal (non-advocating or backed up by anything) rule of thumb is that if you can accomplish your task with a File, go for it. It's way easier to write and manage than database code, and you'll be able to format it for CSV on-the-fly with no conversion needed later. I say don't over-think it. `BufferedWriter` will take care of writing out in large chunks for you, so just keep the output stream open until you're done recording your data and you shouldn't have any latency problems. (don't forget to `flush()` and `close()` when you're done, a rule as appropriate in Java as it is in life).

Comment: "don't forget to flush() and close() when you're done, a rule as appropriate in Java as it is in life" -- LOL!

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would use a SQLite database.  SQLite is very fast, but more importantly, it gives you far more flexibility than a flat file.  You can update the database structure far more easily than a flat file format and you'll be able to sort and search data better, which may be valuable for when yo do have to export it to CSV.

Comment: How many insertions per second can SQLite handle? I'm planning to insert accelerometer data at rates like 2x per second (500 ms intervals) or even 10x per second (100 ms intervals).

Comment: I've never tested that, but SQLite is very fast.  I think it could handle that rate of data as long as you use transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You should see better performance by collecting a large chunk of this data and then writing it to a flat file as a large chunk.  As you mentioned, it will be easier to extract afterwards.